# csv with different encoding

Tags: python, encoding, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open a file in the proper encoding automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342284/open-a-file-in-the-proper-encoding-automatically)

my code:

```
import csv

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
  dataReader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')

for row in dataReader:
  do_sth
```

the problem is that it works well only if csv is UTF-8 encoded. What should I change to serve the iso-8859-2 or windows-1250 encoding?
(the best solution is to autorecognize the encoding, but hand converting is also acceptable)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2342284/624829

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution for now:

```
def reencode(file):
    for line in file:
        yield line.decode('windows-1250').encode('utf-8')

csv_reader = csv.reader(reencode(open(filepath)), delimiter=";",quotechar='"')
```

Comment: this is not he crrect answer , csv documentation : Since open() is used to open a CSV file for reading, the file will by default be decoded into unicode using the system default encoding (see locale.getpreferredencoding()). To decode a file using a different encoding, use the encoding argument of open:

Comment: I was able to open the file with `open(filename, 'r', encoding='latin-1') as f:` and it fixed the encoding errors I was getting.  A standard list of encodings can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [the examples section of the csv module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples).  At the end, you'll find classes you can use for exactly that purpose, specifying the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a file-descriptor opened with [codecs.open](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open). You can't autorecognize encodings, or not very well. To guess the encoding you can use [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet).